# How To Delete Rows in a SQLite Database that may hold the same data depending on which row is selected in a listbox

Tags: c#, winforms, sqlite, listbox

As the title suggests, I want to delete rows of a database depending on which row in a listbox the user will select.[The Listbox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/27Qiq.png). This is my current code, but when run, there is an SQL Logic Error.

```
        string SelectedItemToDelete = LBoxCurrentBasket.SelectedItem.ToString();

        sqlite_conn = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=RetailSystem.db; Version = 3; New = True; Compress = True;");
        sqlite_conn.Open();

        try
        {
            sqlite_cmd = sqlite_conn.CreateCommand();
            sqlite_cmd.CommandText = "DELETE * FROM TblBasket WHERE BasketItemName = @ItemToDelete";
            sqlite_cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ItemToDelete", SelectedItemToDelete);
            SQLiteDataReader sqlite_datareader;
            sqlite_datareader = sqlite_cmd.ExecuteReader();
            sqlite_conn.Close();
            MessageBox.Show("Record Deleted!");
            LBoxCurrentBasket.Refresh();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
```

Also is there a way to merge together the T-Shirt Records so there is only one record with a higher quantity?[The Database if it helps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MOk6w.png)

Comment: While I agree with MarkOn1 that ExecuteNonQuery is more appropriate, `DELETE *` is not valid SQL, [AddWithValue is potentially problematic](https://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/) and you have Disposables that are just left hanging for Finalizers to take care of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you should execute `sqlite_cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();` method instead of executing `sqlite_cmd.ExecuteReader();` on SqliteCommand object.

As per [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.data.sqlite.sqlitecommand.executenonquery?view=msdata-sqlite-6.0.0) SqliteCommand.ExecuteNonQuery method return the number of rows inserted, updated, or deleted.

So, in my opinion I will do it like this:

```
 string SelectedItemToDelete = LBoxCurrentBasket.SelectedItem.ToString();

        sqlite_conn = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=RetailSystem.db; Version = 3; New = True; Compress = True;");
        sqlite_conn.Open();

        try
        {
            sqlite_cmd = sqlite_conn.CreateCommand();
            sqlite_cmd.CommandText = "DELETE FROM TblBasket WHERE BasketItemName = @ItemToDelete";
            sqlite_cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ItemToDelete", SelectedItemToDelete);
            sqlite_cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            MessageBox.Show("Record Deleted!");
            LBoxCurrentBasket.Refresh();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
        finally
        {
          sqlite_conn.Close();
        }
```

Also, don't forget to pass parameters like connection string, and query string to your command object in order to perform the operation on database, as I can see, you did not do that in current state of code .

Comment: You will have the same problem. `DELETE *` is not correct sql syntax.

Comment: Good catch, I didn't see that, totally agree with you, ```*``` is redundant there